# Aiogram. Ошибка при установке библиотеки python

Tags: python, windows, pip, install, aiogram

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку на windows, не получается, переустанавливал microsoft visual c++, пытался в ручную установить библиотеки yarl и multidict, эти библиотеки похожие ошибки выдавали...

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\aiogram-2.10.1> pip install -U aiogram
Collecting aiogram
  Using cached aiogram-2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2019.3.9 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from aiogram) (2020.6.20)
Processing c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\7f\39\5c\ed50902cbc7d59ca6124f3dd079408bcf24ae686906f003ca9\aiohttp-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Babel>=2.6.0
  Using cached Babel-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 MB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-5.0.0.tar.gz (53 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.6.2.tar.gz (177 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.5.4->aiogram) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2015.7 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Babel>=2.6.0->aiogram) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.5.4->aiogram) (2.10)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict, yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpx0h5bafo'
       cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y6nil60b\multidict
  Complete output (46 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\multidict
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcmultidict/_multidict.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\multidict/_multidict.obj -O2
  _multidict.c
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include\pyconfig.h(206): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0smpi54n'
       cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y6nil60b\yarl
  Complete output (41 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\yarl
rams\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcyarl/_quoting_c.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\yarl/_quoting_c.obj
  _quoting_c.c
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include\pyconfig.h(206): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась переустановкой pip на более старую версию